# Maximal risk for the Bayes classifier

Tags: naive-bayes-classifier

In [these](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-657-mathematics-of-machine-learning-fall-2015/86f311c7073869c5e0c199008787d5c9_MIT18_657F15_L2.pdf) lecture notes I found this statement

> This maximal risk for the Bayes classifier occurs precisely when $Y$ “contains no
> information” about the feature variable $X$.

How do I prove it? If I understand this right, then it occurs when $Y$ and $X$ are independent. So $P(Y=1|X=x)$ must be the max when variables are independent but I can't find any statement that proves it.